# list to integer

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to write a recursive python function that takes in a list for example `[1,2,3,4]` and returns an integer `1234`. Any help on how to do this

```
def listtoint(lst):
     if lst==[]:
         return 0
     return lst[-1:]+clti(lst/10)
```

I know you can't divide the list but I would like a way to get around it

Answer (score 3):

```
def listtoint(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return 0
    s = ''.join([str(i) for i in lst])
    return int(s)
```

How this works is: `''.join(some_list)` takes every element of the list and concatenates them into one long string. every element of `some_list` here must already be a string, thus the list comprehension in the code above.

`int` is then used to turn the resulting string into an integer.

There should be error checking but you can deal with that. Also, this isn't recursive and doesn't need to be.

To do this recursively...

```
def listtoint(lst):
    if lst==[]:
         return 0
    iPower = 10**(len(lst)-1)
    return lst[0]*iPower + listtoint(lst[1:])
```

Comment: its recursive because its a question i'm trying to solve

Comment: @RaelWilliams: did you see the second piece of code?